# Odd SVG scaling with -webkit-transform in Mobile Safari / Android Browser

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile, webkit

I am trying to scale an embedded SVG, which is contained inside a div of width 100px, and this SVG is scaled by applying `-webkit-transform: scale(2)` on that div.  On desktops, in both Chrome and Safari, the SVG is correctly scaled to double its original size (i.e., 200px).  However, on an iPad (Mobile Safari) and the Android default browser, the SVG is incorrectly scaled to four times its original size (i.e., 400px).

Similarly, with scale(0.5), desktop browsers correctly scale the SVG to half its original size (i.e., 50px), but the aforementioned mobile browsers scale the SVG to a quarter of its original size (i.e., 25px).

I have tried setting the viewport (via `<meta name="viewport" content="...">`) but it did not correct this behaviour.  Similarly, the SVG's `viewbox` attribute is correctly set, and does not affect it.

Of particular note, however, is that embedding the SVG via `<embed src=>`, `<iframe src=>`, and `<object data=>` tags result in this unwanted behaviour on mobile devices, but `<img src=>` scales perfectly on mobile devices -- however, `<img src=>` brings with it its own set of problems, so I would like to avoid that.

Has anyone experienced something like this?  It's an odd and probably niche question, but I figure someone out there must've encountered this one time or another.